# How Do Custom Initializers Actually "Initialize"?

Tags: swift, initialization

Learning Swift at the moment and it is my first time learning to code as well. I am studying initializers at this point and I am stuck at the idea of custom initializers.

Looking at the code below, I am really not sure how this actually initializes the instances. Isn't setting the value of a property equal to an uninitialized instance just going to result in another un-initialized property?

```
init (region: String, population: Int, stopLights: Int) {
    self.region = region
    self.population = population
    numberOfStoplights = stopLights
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`init` is invoked after memory for your object (struct or class instance) is allocated. At that time the object exists but its fields (member variables) contain unknown (undefined) values.

Swift, for safety and for type consistency, never allows access to undefined values. So you must assign a value to every field of your object in `init`, even if that is just some "default" value. Optional fields are initialized with `nil`.

Comment: I see. So just to make sure I interpreted you correctly: 1) Before we initialize, the value of that instance is undefined, which the compiler cannot handle. But 2) after we have used `init` to initialize it, then that instance becomes an unknown (undefined) value. Although this value is unknown, the compiler will still see this as an acceptable value.

Comment: @GeoffreySetiawan What do you mean by "unknown value"? All properties get assigned values in that initializer.

Comment: @Thilo I guess I am really not understanding this. Ha! So the `init` is assigning the value of the instance `self.region` to `region`. Since `self.region` is going to be an un-initialized value (the whole point of the `init` in the first place), then how can `region` be initialized from the `init`? Sorry...I am really new to Swift, so you might have to dumb it down a little bit...

Comment: No, it's the other way around. `self.region` is initialized with the value of the parameter `region`.  `a = b` changes the value of `a` to become `b`.

Comment: Ah! Makes perfect sense. Thanks @Thilo!

Comment: Yes. I like to think of `a = b` written as `a ← b`. It's an assignment; you're not establishing equivalence.